# Declaring Model Value in Django

Tags: python, django

I am pretty new to Django and I cannot figure out how to declare the value of a model.
For example, if I have a CharField that takes the choice of three sizes s, m, l. Then auto-populate the value for length and width. So, it would be something like this.

```
s = {
"length": 5,
"width": 7
}
m = {
"length": 8,
"width": 10
}
l = {
"length": 12,
"width": 18
}
CHOICE_LIST = [
("s", "Small"),
("m", "Medium"),
("l", "Large")
]
size = models.CharField(choices = CHOICE_LIST)
length = models.IntegerField()
width = models.IntegerField()
```

Then somehow make the model instances length and width = the dictionary length width based on model instances size. So, if you inputted small it would make length 5 and width 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `length` and `width` are dependent on `size`. You can just store size and add the other two attributes as properties that are calculated based on the size

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    SIZES = {
        "s": {
            "label": "Small",
            "length": 8,
            "width": 10,
        },
        "m": {
            "label": "Medium",
            "length": 5,
            "width": 7,
        },
        "l": {
            "label": "Large",
            "length": 12,
            "width": 18,
        }
    }
    size = models.CharField(choices=[(k, v["label"]) for k, v in SIZES.items()])

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.SIZES[self.size]["length"]

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self.SIZES[self.size]["width"]
```

Comment: Do you have to run the method somewhere to get the length and width to populate?

Comment: @TonyDean no, so long as `size` has been set then both those properties should return values

Answer (score 1):

Even though lain's solution seems way more efficient, I'm still going to post my answer that will maybe help you for a future reference.

```
class Size(models.Model):
    CHOICE_LIST = [
        ("s", "Small"),
        ("m", "Medium"),
        ("l", "Large")
    ]
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICE_LIST)
    length = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        s = {
            "length": 5,
            "width": 7
        }
        m = {
            "length": 8,
            "width": 10
        }
        l = {
            "length": 12,
            "width": 18
        }

        if self.size == 's':
            self.length = s['length']
            self.width = s['width']

        if self.size == 'm':
            self.length = m['length']
            self.width = m['width']

        if self.size == 'l':
            self.length = l['length']
            self.width = l['width']

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This can be done also by overriding the save method. This is not ideal to the auto-populate the fields before saving but after saving. And also, you should note where I have `models.IntegerField(default=0)` where the `default=0` will assign it a value before saving. In this solution, if there is not a default value you won't be able to save it. But it works perfectly after saving if there is a default value.

For future reference you can use the knowledge of overriding the save method to include other functions to work as you save.

Answer (score 0):

There's the length of the actual database field, which you specify in `max_length`, and there's your own choice entries which you supply as a sequence consisting of iterables of exactly two items. For example:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
   CHOICES = [
        ('s', 'length: 5 and width: 7'),
        ('m', 'medium'),
        ('l', (5, 7)),
    ]
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, choices= CHOICES, verbose_name="sizing")
```

more examples in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices).